# Application crashes when opening a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5

I’m using Qt 5.0.0 on Windows 7 ×64 (personal compile – MinGW x64). I added MySQL support in configuration and also MySQL is installed on system. MySQL libraries, headers and are visible in application.

Program crashes on opening database. I open database like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setDatabaseName("My DB name");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("My password");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
try{
db.open(); // <=== Crashes without throwing an exception
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

**Notes:**

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

prints

```
("QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL", "QODBC3", "QODBC", "QSQLITE")
```

Problem signature generated by operating system looks like this:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: CMS.exe
Application Version: 0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp: 51010cdd
Fault Module Name: Qt5Sql.dll
Fault Module Version: 5.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 50f6b734
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 00000000000df950
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: db69
Additional Information 2: db697f824a06df6631cf05ed1f197e16
Additional Information 3: 1d76
Additional Information 4: 1d7605bf295c1c2cfcbfc6bfcec7c569
```

I generate .a file using gendef and dlltool this way:

```
gendef libmysql.dll
dlltool --input-def libmysql.def --dllname libmysql.dll --output-lib libmysql.a
```

Qt is configured with `-qt-sql-mysql` rather than `-plugin-sql-mysql`. ( What is difference? )

Comment: Do you actually call `db.open()`?

Comment: c0000005 is `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. You are doing something wrong - e.g. you are trying to access a database without it existing, or you having the rights to do so.
Explicitly verify that no operations in your workflow return an error code (could `db` be actually `NULL`?), retrieve error details if it does so, and try to pinpoint what instruction triggers the exception.

Comment: @lserni I checked `db` it's not null. Everything looks good. Database exists and has data.

Comment: db isn't a pointer, so it cannot be null. Even if there's an error, QtSql must not crash. Might well be a bug in QtSql. Try with a Qt debug build, minimal test case and create a Qt bug report if the problems remains.

Comment: Also, please show the code calling open() and its surroundings.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I already tried debugging. Updated my question. See `db.open()` code.

Comment: For those who interested in issue or want to take a look at, I released my SDK at https://sourceforge.net/projects/eboqt/ .

Answer (score 1):

Since your program is crashing without catching the exception (and I note that you've written as a catch-all) I would tend to assume the crash is happening BEFORE the try block.

Try wrapping the declaration of 'db' and the setting of it's properties in a try-catch (even if only temporarily).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that the original DLLs of MySQL connectors are compiled with MSVC. On the other hand, there is a significant/undocumented ABI incompatiblity between MinGW and MSVC on x64 platform. So I re-compiled MySQL with MinGW-64 then everything works.